# listing inside a container - HTML Problem

Tags: html

I am trying to show the screen like in the image

[list inside a container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hr69.png)
[image]
the problem is the whatever I do, the list is on the bottom of the container [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwxPG.png)

[image]

the HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-init="getCartItems()">
    <div class="hidden-xs">
        <div class="">
            <div class="title">סיכום הזמנה</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-include="'templates/cart.html'"></div>
        <div class="subTotalTabs">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
                    <li><a href="home" class="clickable btn btn-lg borderBox padTop5 padBtm5 f22">הוספת מבצע</a></li>
                    <li><a ng-click="addToCart()" class="clickable btn btn-lg borderBox padTop5 padBtm5 f22">הוספת פיצה</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pickDrink" class="clickable btn btn-lg borderBox padTop5 padBtm5 f22">הוספת שתייה</a></li>
                    <li><a href="otherFood" class="clickable btn btn-lg borderBox padTop5 padBtm5 f22">מוצרים נלווים</a></li>
                    <li><a ng-click="clearCart()" class="my-btn-sqr my-btn-sqr-danger padTop5 padBtm5 f22">רוקן עגלה</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->
</div>
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

`

Comment: To start with, it looks like you need to get rid of one of those `</div>` just before closing the row.

Comment: Take the time to do proper indentation. Then it becomes obvious that there is a mismatch in closing tags.